# Windows File History to FTP

Tags: windows-10, ftp, network-drive, file-history, versioning

I'm trying to make Windows 10 File History tool use my FTP server for backup and especially versioning.

I've ran into problems. No matter what I do, the File History tool doesn't see, allow or otherwise work with the location I end up creating.

- I tried setting up a network location (ftp) in Explorer, sharing it to myself, then making FH use the resulting network share, but the share isn't a folder but a shortcut file and it cannot be selected.
- I tried mapping this share to a network drive, but the resulting location only contains... a shortcut file.
- I used ftpuse to mount the ftp location as a drive, but FH doesn't see it (neither does Disk Manager).
- Sharing that to myself (again) creates a share which is a folder, and FH can select it, but then it says the resource is unavailable.

Is there a normal, simple way to do it? Or should I just give up and try other (which?) versioning software?

Answer (score 0):

An easy-to-use utility that mounts remote file systems as Windows drives via SFTP. Once connected, you can browse and work with files as if they were stored on your local machine

SFTP Net Drive - https://www.nsoftware.com/sftp/netdrive/

it's free for private use.

Comment: Does that work with the File History features? If so, *how*?

Comment: It does, it backups and you can restore files as normal.

Comment: I tested it a year ago and unfortunately it wouldn't work with my server whatsoever (FTP over TLS). The developer recommended waiting for CallBackDrive which was supposed to support SCP (which is great!), and seems to have become **CBFS Connect**.